# Setting a Text Area's Value with PHP from a Text Document

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to get my text area's value to be set via my text document using php. I've got it working correctly however, it's adding a ton of spaces before and after. Looks like this`(         COMMENT TEXT HERE!             )` bear in mind by text document has only spaces between the words nothing else.
Anyone know why?

```
   <form action="GeneralImpressionPt3.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name"FileForm" id="FileForm">
    <label for="FormField"></label>
    <p align="center">Additional Comments</p>

    <textarea name="date3" rows="15">
    <?php 
        $myFile=fopen("TextTest.txt","r") or exit("Can’t open file!");
        echo fgets($myFile);
        fclose($myFile);        
    ?>
     </textarea>                 

    <div id="loginBtnDiv">
    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Next">
    </div>

    </form>
```

Comment: might not fix this, but you have a syntax error here `name"FileForm"` missing an `=` for it.

Comment: what will fix this though, is that you have a bunch of spaces between `<textarea name="date3" rows="15">` and `</textarea>` in the PHP area, and those count as spaces.

Comment: Yup, it's your indentation that's doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I stated in comments, you have a bunch of spaces inside `<textarea name="date3" rows="15">` and `</textarea>` in the PHP area, and those count as spaces.

```
   <form action="GeneralImpressionPt3.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="FileForm" id="FileForm">
    <label for="FormField"></label>
    <p align="center">Additional Comments</p>

<textarea name="date3" rows="15">
<?php 
$myFile=fopen("TextTest.txt","r") or exit("Can't open file!");
echo fgets($myFile);
fclose($myFile);
?>
</textarea>

    <div id="loginBtnDiv">
    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Next">
    </div>

    </form>
```

and you have a syntax error here `name"FileForm"` missing an `=` sign and could play some nasty tricks on you, if your code is dependent on it.

- `name="FileForm"`

I also changed that curly quote `’` to a regular quote `'`, just in case as that may throw a parse error.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: @MattHutch You're most welcome. *Cheers* glad to have helped.

Answer (score 0):

```
textarea{
    white-space: normal;
}
```

Edit your css-code, this will work.

Comment: that will probably get rid of the spaces coming from his text file also.